# Laravel 5.5 Passing database fields to app.blade.php

Tags: laravel

I am building an app in Laravel. There is a table `MeTags` with fields (id, pageName, title, description, keywords). I want to show title, description and keywords on each page. For that I am using Laravel view composer, so that I can use these fields on every page.

I made a new provider ViewComposerServiceProvider and added my code in boot() function

```
public function boot()
{        
    view()->composer('app', function($view) {
        $settings = DB::table('MeTags')->get();
        foreach ($settings as $setting) { 
            $view->with('title', $setting->title);
        }
    });
}
```

Then I added that provider in config/app.php

```
App\Providers\ViewComposerServiceProvider::class
```

When i call this title variable in app.blade.php

```
<title>{{ $title }}</title>
```

I get the following error

> Undefined variable: title (View: C:\wamp64\www\myProject\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php) (View: C:\wamp64\www\myProject\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php)

Am i missing something?

I am new to Laravel, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That view isn't `app` its `layouts.app`.

Also your loop is just setting the same variable over and over again.